# Does git pull and git pull --all the same?

Tags: git, github

I only have `master` branch locally and i have remote branches `master` and `branch1`.

when i run `git pull` and `git pull --all`, seems these two commands are the same, i have thought `git pull` only pull the code on my local current branch.

So these two commands are the same?

The only difference is `Fetching origin` in the log.

PS: the log

```
git pull --all
Fetching origin
fdc1162..8b6f103  master     -> origin/master
86ce60d..ef1cd89  branch1    -> origin/branch1

git pull
8b6f103..713ae5e  master     -> origin/master
ef9f2f9..8d542eb  branch1    -> origin/branch1
```

---**EDIT**---

I think i got it. `git pull --all` not means all the branches on one server, which means for more than one servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git pull --all` fetches from all configured remotes. `git pull` only pulls from the default remote.